# How to Crop Geotiff without GDAL using GUI based tool?

Tags: geospatial, gdal, geotiff

I need to crop Geotiff files without using command line GDAL.  I am looking for a GUI based Geotiff or related file editor.  I need to freely select any area to crop.  I need to preserve lat long information so I can merge multiple Geotiff files.  I would not mind converting Geotiff files to some other format and then crop and convert to Geotiff.

Comment: obituary? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obituary?s=t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a desktop GIS. Qgis: http://www.qgis.org/ will do it along with a zillion other mappy things, or there's gvSIG, OpenJUMP, uDIG and others, see www.osgeo.org or search. Did I mention these are all free and open source?

Another idea is to use R, the statistics package. It can read in Geotiffs, plot them, allow selection from the graphics window, subsetting, and saving, but it is a programming language so a bit of typing is necessary. The process would be something like this:

```
r = raster("myraster.tiff")
plot(r)
bounds = locator(2) # you then click corners for cropping
c = crop(r,bounds)  # might be 'extract' or 'mask' or something...
plot(c) 
writeRaster(c,"clipped.tiff")
```

Excuse the vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be interested, we have started to work on an open source GUI utility, **Rasterix**, using GDAL and the Qt framework.

It can perform some of the tasks already implemented in several GDAL command line utilities for raster processing, but using a friendly graphical user interface.

The complete **source code** and the pre-built **binaries for Windows, Linux and macOS** are hosted on github at https://github.com/mogasw/rasterix.

We will add more features in the future, but should you be interested in something in particular, please let us know using github's issues.